# Add and normalize rows where keys repeat in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I add and normalize (divide by total row sum) all rows with repetitive key (having key-column sorted)?

Consider pandas df

```
key | f1 | f2 | f3
1   | 0  |  1 | 0
1   | 1  |  0 | 0
2   | 0  |  0 | 1
2   | 0  |  0 | 1
3   | 1  |  0 | 1
```

and desired output

```
key | f1 | f2 | f3
1   | 0.5| 0.5| 0
2   | 0  |  0 | 1
3   | 0.5|  0 | 0.5
```

In output key column has unique values.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply reuse your `GroupBy` sum object

```
g = df.groupby('key')
s = g.sum()

s/s.sum(1).values
```

---

```
    f1  f2  f3
key         
1   0.5 0.5 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 1.0
3   0.5 0.0 0.5
```

Comment: this worked for me -- sum = s.div(s.sum(axis=1), axis=0)